# Разделить на admin и user роутинг в Kohana

Tags: php, kohana-3, маршрутизация

Не могу понять почему не работает такая карта маршрутов

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'home_Admin',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'user',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

При переходе по `test.app/` или `test.app/admin`, вылетает следующее

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Причина этого не понятна. Кто сталкивался с подобного рода задачей ?

Comment: А классы какие используются? Сам с Kohana не знаком, но везде (в поиске), где встречается такая ошибка, было что-то не так с классами, т.е. либо класс, либо метод отсутствует, либо именование неправильное было.

Иногда проскакивали ошибки с RewriteEngine апача. С ним все хорошо, он включен/настроен/работает?

Проблема только с админкой? Другие запросы обрабатываются?

Comment: Бэкенд - это вся серверная часть, на выходе которой только данные, фронтенд - то, что генерирует вывод для пользователя.

К разделению админка/публичные страницы это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @BOPOH всё с классами в порядке

Comment: > не нужно пудрить людям мозги :)

я как раз о том, что не нужно вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: RewriteEngine работает? Другие запросы обрабатываются?

И все же мне не нравится ваш `home_Admin`, я все-таки предлагаю вам поменять его имя, хотя бы для проверки, например, на `admin` (и класс в контроллере поменять не забудьте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексный файл админки (/admin), который должен работать, лежит в

```
/application/classes/Coontroller/backend/home/Admin.php 
// class Controller_backend_home_Admin
```

Судя из роутера, он должен быть именно таким.

Индексный основного сайта должен лежать в

```
/application/classes/Coontroller/frontend/home.php
// class Controller_frontend_home
```

Имена файлов и папок в том же регистре, что и в роутере?
В linux File.txt и file.txt два разных файла.

Comment: И я про то же, но говорят, что с классами все в порядке )